# slice option in plot function of package e1071

Tags: r, plot, svm

I'm using the e1071 package in R. Just wondering what the slice option of the plot function does in the code below. I have read the manual for the package but did not understand what it said.

```
iris.svm <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris, probability = TRUE)
plot(iris.svm, data = iris, Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, slice = list(Sepal.Width = 3, Sepal.Length = 6))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?plot.svm`

> slice       a list of named numeric values for the dimensions held constant (only needed if more than two variables are used). Dimensions not specified are fixed at 0.

In other words, when visualising the effect of predictor variables on the response you can specify which *other* predictor variables are to be hold constant (i.e. at a fixed value).

So in your example, you're visualising the effect of the predictor variables `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width` on the response while keeping `Sepal.Width` and `Sepal.Length` constant at the specified values.

[image]